# More cunning? Was the serpent really more cunning?

Tags: genesis, grammar

The direct translation of [Gen 3:1](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/3-1.htm) is that the serpent was cunning out of the living of the field.

- The word for 'beast' in our English Bibles is the Hebrew word for 'living'.
- The word for 'more' is not used in this sentence? Am I right?
- 'Cunning' is *arum* which also means 'naked'.  Adam and Eve were also *arum* / naked.

Thus, the serpent wasn't MORE *arum* than anything living, he was just *arum*, like Adam and Eve.

**Am I reading this correctly?** Even when using an Interlinear Bible and a Hebrew translator I cannot find the word for 'more' in this verse. If I am right, this will change a lot of things.

Also, notice how the word for 'serpent' is actually derived from the verb which means 'to practice divination', so the noun would mean 'someone/thing that is divining'.  And this 'thing' which is translated 'serpent' was as *arum* as Adam and Eve was

**Was it really something outside of Eve?** Or was it the hiss of her inner spirit which led to her questioning God's command?

Answer (score 3):

Hebrew lacks adjectives with comparative (elative) forms. Instead, it uses the prefixed מ to indicate comparison. (Also, see [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/38468/does-genesis-31-imply-that-god-did-not-create-serpents) and [this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/38470/27191).)

As Joüon and Muraoka note,<sup>1</sup>

[image]

Examples include,

[image]

---

| Footnotes |
| --- |
| <sup>1</sup> Joüon, Muraoka, §141g, p. 487. Also, see Ewald, §519, p. [327](https://books.google.com/books?id=6LbFV0pYTP4C&pg=PA327#v=onepage&q&f=false); Gesenius, §133, p. [429–432](https://archive.org/details/geseniushebrewgr00geseuoft/page/428/mode/2up); Pratico, Van Pelt, §6.6.1., p. [53–54](https://books.google.com/books?id=p3FIoT0s3yYC&lpg=PA1&pg=PT66#v=onepage&q&f=false) (2nd ed.) |

| References |
| --- |
| Joüon, Paul; Muraoka, Tamitsu. [*Grammar of Biblical Hebrew.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oJY06MoeEb4C) 3rd Reprint. 2nd ed. Rome: Gregorian & Biblical Press, 2011. |

Comment: Thank you - is that a Hebrew mem that is added as a prefix?

Comment: @LisaCremer—Yes. The prefixed mem מ is of course short for the preposition מִן.

Answer (score 1):

@ Welcome to you to be part of this site, from today on.

As regards your question, maybe could be useful to you to read an answer I posted about 8 months ago ([Why is עֲרוּמִּ֔ים (Gen 2:25) translated "naked," and in the very next verse its singular form, עָר֔וּם (Gen 3:1), is translated "crafty/shrewd?"](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/38632/why-is-%d7%a2%d6%b2%d7%a8%d7%95%d6%bc%d7%9e%d6%bc%d6%b4%d6%94%d7%99%d7%9d-gen-225-translated-naked-and-in-the-very-next-verse-its)).

Even if it does not answer *exactly* to your question, I believe it contains some interesting points that brings to light a number of pivotal concepts useful for your current research.

By.

Answer (score 1):

Genesis 3:1

> Now the serpent was more crafty than any of the wild animals the LORD God had made.

The word for 'more' is not used in this sentence? Am i right?

As pointed out by Übermensch, Hebrew does not have an adverb like 'more'. Instead, the 'more' concept is expressed by the prefix, מִ

than any
מִכֹּל֙ (mik·kōl)
Preposition-m | Noun - masculine singular construct
Strong's 3605: The whole, all, any, every

The prefix works like the greater than symbol, >.

crafty, cunning
עָר֔וּם (‘ā·rūm)
Adjective - masculine singular
Strong's 6175: Crafty, shrewd, sensible

Genesis 2:25

> Adam and his wife were both naked, and they felt no shame.

naked,
עֲרוּמִּ֔ים (‘ă·rūm·mîm)
Adjective - masculine plural
Strong's 6174: Nude, either partially, totally

The two Hebrew words are different but related.

Was the serpent really something outside of Eve?

Yes. Genesis 3:

> 14 So the LORD God **said** to the **serpent**:
> “Because you have done this,
> cursed are you above all livestock
> and every beast of the field!
> On your belly will you go,
> and dust you will eat,
> all the days of your life.
> 15And I will put enmity between you and the woman,
> and between your seed and her seed.
> He will crush your head,
> and you will strike his heel.”

God did not speak to a figment of Eve's inner imagination. The serpent was external and real.