Why the serpent was more crafty than any of the wild animals the Lord God made?
Genesis 3:1 states:
"Now the serpent was more crafty than any of the wild animals the Lord God had made."
Who claims that the serpent was more crafty than any of the wild animals the Lord God had made? Is it God Himself or the author of Genesis? I ask this because I don't see the attributes that make the serpent more crafty. Animals that work in groups, such as wolves, hyenas, and even bees, seem far more crafty to me.

Your question is likely a duplicate. See Why is עֲרוּמִּ֔ים (Gen 2:25) translated "naked," and in the very next verse its singular form, עָר֔וּם (Gen 3:1), is translated "crafty/shrewd?"
However, let me offer what might be generously termed an "originalist" view (or less generously, a "naive" view).
Speculations on Genesis and the Serpent

Now the serpent was more cunning than any beast of the field which
Yahweh had made.  – Genesis 3:1 literal Hebrew


But the serpent was most skilled of all of the wild beasts upon the
earth whom The Lord God made. – Genesis 3:1 literal Greek from the
Septuagint (practical, skilled, intelligent)

The Hebrew root for nachash (נָחָשׁ) is the basis for a noun, a verb, and an adjective. As a masculine noun, it can mean serpent (the feminine version means bronze), as a verb it can mean deceiver or diviner, and as an adjective it can mean shining. Serpent, deceiver, diviner, shining. How interesting!
Concerning the word, “cunning” in Hebrew (עָר֔וּם), the word is used seven times in the Bible. Six of those times, which are all in Proverbs, the Hebrew word is translated prudent or sensible. In the Greek Septuagint, translated from Hebrew into Greek under the auspices of the Jewish Sanhedrin, we read φρόνιμος (phronimos), which means practical, skilled, or intelligent in Greek (wise, prudent).
It’s also interesting to note that the difference between the Hebrew words for cunning (עָר֔וּם, ‘ā·rūm) and naked (עָר֛וֹם, ‘ā·rō·wm) is only in the vowels that were used, which were added as "vowel points" by the Masoretes much later during medieval times, the 500s through the 900s AD.
Serpents Weren't Snakes
The image of Eve and Adam, who was there with her, being tempted by a snake is a great example of the problems encountered when people bring preconceptions into the scriptures. It's easy to do.
Certainly, medieval painters did so, as well as scholars of ancient near-eastern literature and philosophy.
Genesis 3 Taken Literally
Let's lay aside our own preconceptions for a moment and consider what the first part of Genesis literally asserts.

It's the account of God's creation of the heaven and the earth.
God created various types of animals first and then humans, male and female.
God commanded them to sexually reproduce and fill the earth.
The most “cunning” (or “naked”) of all the wild animals that God created was named "serpent" by Adam.
Serpents, whatever they were, apparently could speak the language of humans, otherwise the passage wouldn’t bother to explain that the serpent was more cunning than all the other animals. One such serpent tricked humans into disobeying God's command.
God pronounced a judgment on all humans and either all serpents or just this one, and predicted hatred between Eve and the serpent. Eve’s offspring (singular) and the serpent’s offspring (singular) would continue this hatred.
The serpent would wound the heel of Eve’s offspring (singular), but Eve’s offspring (singular) would crush the head of the serpent, killing him.

Inferences Based on Genesis 3
Our inferences about serpents include the following:

Serpents were also created male and female, and commanded to reproduce as did all the other animals that God created.
Serpents were more intelligent than orangutans, parrots and crows, tucuxi dolphins, and octopuses. Currently, tucuxi dolphins are considered the most intelligent wild animal on earth today.
Perhaps all serpents except this one perished in the flood. The one that survived is “the fleeing serpent” mentioned in Isaiah and Job, and “the serpent of old” mentioned in Revelation, and also called Leviathan and “the Dragon.”
Before God cursed serpents—or at least that serpent—THEY DID NOT CRAWL ALONG THE GROUND AS SNAKES, otherwise God’s pronouncement would be pointless and stupid, and wouldn’t have been a curse. The imagery of eating dust may come from the lowly snake whose tongue flickers near the ground to pick up the scent of prey. However, an animal that actually does eat dirt is the earthworm.
The motive of this serpent to deceive the humans is not stated. We do know that serpents were created before humans, but humans were given stewardship over the earth and all plant and animal life. Perhaps, this serpent, under the instigation of satan, became jealous, just as Cain later became jealous of Abel. With the death of humans, serpents could then take primacy over the earth. Or perhaps satan incarnated himself conveniently as a serpent, while Messiah would be incarnated as a human. I'm intentionally lower casing "satan" because it's not a name, but a description. In Hebrew satan (שָׂטָן) literally means "adversary/accuser" and is pronounced sah 'tahn. His name will be forgotten forever.
Perhaps Eve believed that she herself would give birth to the one who would crush the serpent's head. She named her first son Cain, which in Hebrew means “acquired,” and she is quoted as saying, “I have acquired a man from Yahweh.” The Septuagint translation is “I have acquired a man through (or on account of) Yahweh.” Eve’s desire might thus be a reasonable interpretation of “the desire of women” alluded to in Daniel 11 and fulfilled by Mary’s giving birth to Jesus, the Messiah.

Further Study
https://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/OTpdf/gen3.pdf
What's the meaning of Genesis 3:15? - The Case for Messiah (One for Israel)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdOxc-nvh1k

According to the "A Demonstration of The Apostolic Teaching by Irenæus", the "serpent" was the "archangel" placed as the "steward" over Earth and Paradise. I believe many here would benefit from having a read.
Chapter 11

And there were in this place also with (their) tasks the servants of
that God who formed all things; and the steward, who was set over all
his fellow servants received this place. Now the servants were angels,
and the steward was the archangel.
Now, having made man lord of the earth and all things in it, He
secretly appointed him lord also of those who were servants in it.
They however were in their perfection; but the lord, that is, man, was
(but) small; for he was a child; and it was necessary that he should
grow, and so come to (his) perfection.

The Demonstration of the Apostolic Preaching — Irenæus - Chapter 11
Chapter 16

This commandment the man kept not, but was disobedient to God, being
led astray by the angel who, for the great gifts of God which He had
given to man, was envious and jealous of him, and both brought himself
to nought and made man sinful, persuading him to disobey the
commandment of God. So the angel, becoming by his falsehood the author
and originator of sin, himself was struck down, having offended
against God, and man he caused to be cast out from Paradise. And,
because through the guidance of his disposition he apostatized and
departed from God, he was called Satan, according to the Hebrew word;
that is, Apostate: a but he is also called Slanderer. Now God cursed
the serpent which carried and conveyed the Slanderer; and this
malediction came on the beast himself and on the angel hidden and
concealed in him, even on Satan; and man He put away from His
presence, removing him and making him to dwell on the way to Paradise
at that time; because Paradise receiveth not the sinful.

The Demonstration of the Apostolic Preaching — Irenæus - Chapter 16
So, being an "elohim", a top one at that, I'd surmise that he'd be quite cunning.

Previously in this story, God speaks:
Gen.2

18 The Lord God said: "It is not good for the man to be alone. I will
make a helper suited to him."

But in Gen. 3:1 the speaker is the narrator. Whether the narrator is God or not is a theological question: did God write Genesis, did Moses, or is it the work of a later author/authors. However, the simple answer to the OP question is that the speaker is the narrator.
As to why the serpent is described as the most crafty: This was no ordinary serpent such as a snake or a Komodo dragon today. It was a sentient being, capable of speech with humans. It operated not from instinct but from conscious intent to seduce. It is in that sense this serpent was called more crafty than the wild animals. Christian theology understands the serpent as something other than a mere animal. Rather, it was either a symbol of the devil, or the form that the devil assumed.

As I have detailed elsewhere, the creation narratives in Genesis are polemic, corrective response to alternate creation narratives and stories in the culture surrounding Israel, such as such as the Epic of Atra-hasis, or the Enûma Eliš and a few others.
For example in Enûma Eliš  (and by extension the Epic of Atra-hasis) there are the monster Tiamat and Abzu which represent primordial waters (the formless and void which are divided in Genesis). These are slain and divided by Marduk in the story with one becoming sea waters. There is some evidence to suggest that Tiamat was serpent or dragon like in appearance.
The serpent is also present in the text of the creation myth recorded on the Barton Cylinder
The same serpent motif is seen in Egyptian mythology. According to Egyption mythos, the sun god Ra rode in a boat, the Solar Barque Mesektet. Each night, this boat was attacked by a creature of the underworld, Apep which was depicted as a serpent was said to have battled "at the Persea tree" and the fruit of this tree was regarded in Egyption myth to be life-giving. According to Coffin Spell Text 160,

His [Apep's] name is "He overthrows"

Quite a coincidence!
In a competing Egyptian creation story, the Ogdoad which originated from Hermopolis, the goddesses of the story are depicted as serpents.
If we accept the Genesis creation story as a response to creative texts of other cultures around Israel, it is then influenced by those stories. Since the serpents in Babylonian and Egyptian creation stories were depicted as being wily and crafty in those narratives, this is likely the reason the author elected to use that particular adjective in Genesis.

We may find it perplexing that in Genesis and Revelation, the serpent is depicted as Satan, punished by God to crawl on its belly and eat dust all its life (Genesis 3:14) and ultimately cast into the lake of fire. However, in Numbers 21:9, Moses was commanded to create a bronze serpent that provided healing to those who looked at it. Today, the World Health Organization uses a similar symbol, the Rod of Asclepius-a snake entwined around a pole, as part of its official logo. This symbol is universally associated with health and medicine.
Could it be possible that the serpent is a metaphor for the sinful nature of humanity? The punishment in Genesis 3:14 may symbolize the hardships humanity faces when cast out from God's care. By looking at the serpent, an analogy for facing our sins and repenting, we receive healing and salvation. Ultimately, God will take away our sins and cast them into the lake of fire.
I don't have a definitive answer, but this interpretation seems reasonable to me.

As regards your question, maybe could be useful to you to read an answer I posted (https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/62359/22234) about 4 years ago (Why is עֲרוּמִּ֔ים [Gen 2:25] translated "naked", and in the very next verse its singular form, עָר֔וּם (Gen 3:1), is translated "crafty/shrewd?").
Even if it does not answer exactly to your question, I believe it contains some interesting points that brings to light a number of pivotal concepts useful for your current research.
